# Which mild pepper is a good substitute for Serrano pepper?

Tags: substitutions, chili-peppers

I plan to make a guacamole dip and one of the ingredients is Serrano pepper, which is 10,000 to 23,000 heat units by the [Scoville scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoville_scale).

That is way too spicy for me.

Which one of the milder peppers (100-2,000) would be a good replacement?

Comment: One option is to simply use less of 'em, especially if their primary purpose is for heat.

Comment: Also, the capsaicin (the hot substance in any pepper) is concentrated in the membrane that holds the seeds. Strip that out and the pepper will be much milder.

Comment: I second Elendil's comment - have you actually tried a carefully seeded serrano in anything? I may have a higher tolerance than you, but it doesn't seem very hot to me at at that point.

Comment: @Jefromi: No, I haven't consciously tried a hot pepper of any kind. Only once, jalapeno, with seeds, by mistake. Not fun.

Comment: Then how do you know that a serrano minus seeds and membrane, as a small part of guacamole, is "way too spicy"? A raw, intact jalapeno by itself would be a bit much for me too.

Comment: I don't. I was judging by the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

US Jalapeno and Anahiems (red jalapenos) are usually under 2,500. If you cook them a little bit, it will also reduce the spiciness, while maintaining the flavor.

Comment: Did you mean fry or boil them?

Comment: I would throw them into the frying pan with a little bit of oil. Boiling might work, but I haven't tried it. BTW, what other people said above about removing seeds is crucial.

Answer (score 5):

[Anaheim peppers make a nice substitute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaheim_pepper), first in reducing the heat (500-5000 scoville), but also in terms of its availability and similar flavor. It does frequently run on the hotter end of that spectrum though.

Comment: You were right about availability. Anaheim was easy to find and worked perfectly (seeded and raw).

Answer (score 3):

You can just omit them if you don't want any heat. Otherwise, Anaheim or Jalapeno would be fine choices.

Answer (score 0):

Chopped green peppers are a great substitute if you absolutely don't want any hotness to your dish.  I used poblano peppers are a great substitute and they register as a'1' on the hotness scale.