# What is a substitute for Anaheim Peppers?

Tags: substitutions, chili-peppers

I am making a dish that requires Anaheim Peppers.  They don't have them in my local store... what else can I use.

Comment: What sort of dish is it? This answer can very depending on dish. I would replace Anaheim peppers with Jalapeños on a burger, but may substitute for banana peppers if it was a salad.

Comment: Related, but up a few SHUs: [Which mild pepper is a good substitute for Serrano pepper?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13594/15)

Answer (score 3):

You need to substitute a mild pepper . . . be careful not to add something much hotter or you may change the whole concept of the dish . . . unless of course you are trying to kick up the heat a bit.

As suggested, a Poblano is the best substitute. Other names for Anaheim peppers are: California Green Chile; Long Green Pepper; and Chile Verde.

Answer (score 2):

Poblanos are a good substitute, and are pretty common. any mild green pepper would probably be ok. (note: they also call anaheim peppers "new mexico", so maybe they are just labeled differently?)

Comment: They also just call them "green chilies", and New Mexicans would argue that this is the correct name. "Anaheim" is a mild varietal of the basic critter. Poblanos tend to run hotter than Anaheims---more like the green chilies they grow around Hatch, but they *do* make a good substitute.

Comment: New Mexico and Anaheim are apparently different peppers--the New Mexico are a bit hotter. http://www.foodsubs.com/Chilefre.html

Comment: They are the same pepper. Green Chile from New Mexico is bred hotter, so it is often classified differently for cooking. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaheim_pepper

Answer (score 0):

Look for Cubano peppers or (less likely) Hungarian peppers.

Answer (score 0):

Hungarian pointed pepper. It's strong:)