# What is a substitute for Poblano Peppers?

Tags: substitutions, chili-peppers

I have a recipe that calls for Poblano peppers but our store does not have them. I found [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15306/what-is-a-substitute-for-anaheim-peppers) which references using Anaheim Peppers but they don't have those either.

What is a good alternative?

It is a roasted stuffed pepper dish that I need them for.

Comment: Not an alternative, but look to see if there are any latin or international markets near you.  Poblanos are relatively thin skinned, so bell peppers plus some other hot pepper for seasoning might throw off the balance and/or cooking time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stuff any pepper which is large enough.

Poblano are moderately spicy.  You can use bell peppers, but they will not be spicy.  You might want to make up for that by including some spicier small peppers in your stuffing, perhaps a serrano or a jalapeno or seventeen, depending on your personal taste.

Comment: _seventeen_ peppers....that would be hot

Comment: @bluefeet No accounting for taste :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will keep this in mind.  I am going to check out a few more stores to see if I can find the poblanos. :)

Comment: Hatch chiles or larger Californias might work as well.